# Nativescript scroll to bottom of ScrollView programmatically

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

In my Nativescript Angular application, I have a TextView within a ScrollView, defined as such:

```
<ScrollView orientation="vertical" height="70%" width="100%" style="margin-bottom: 1%; background-color:white" (loaded)="onScrollerLoaded($event)">
    <TextView 
        id="terminal" [text]="terminalText" editable="false"
        style="color: whitesmoke; background-color: black; font-size: 8%; font-family: monospace" height="100%"     
        (tap)="onTap($event)" (loaded)="onTerminalLoaded($event)">
    </TextView>
</ScrollView>
```

The purpose of this element is to act as a terminal, and is rapidly printing incoming messages from a bluetooth device.

Currently, the ScrollView is scrolling back to the top whenever I add some text to the `terminalText` variable, to which the TextView is bound. **I would like to be able to keep the ScrollView at the bottom of the TextView.**

---

A few notes:

I am adding text to the `terminalText` variable within my associated component class through this method:

```
public appendToTerminal(appendStr){
    this.terminalText += appendStr;
}
```

I have tried implementing the following code that would execute once the ScrollView loads:

```
private scrollIntervalId;
onScrollerLoaded(data: EventData){
    if(!this.scrollIntervalId){
        this.scrollIntervalId = setInterval(()=>{
            this.ngZone.run(() =>
                (data.object as any).scrollToVerticalOffset((data.object as any).scrollableHeight, false)
            )
        }, 10);
    }
}
```

(This attempt is based on an explanation given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304993/auto-scroll-to-bottom)

I have only tried this on an Android device, as I do not have access to an Apple device.

Comment: on scrollview load it is working or not?

Comment: @bhavinjalodara It's working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you are setting `TextView` to fixed height 100% which is will be same as `ScrollView` that is why `scrollableHeight` will always be 0. you should use `minHeight="100%"`.

then you can scroll programmatically to the end when you are appending text to terminal text `this.terminalText += appendStr`.

like this

```
public appendToTerminal(appendStr){
    this.terminalText += appendStr;
    setTimeout(()=>{
        scrollView.scrollToVerticalOffset(scrollView.scrollableHeight, false);

    },150);
}
```

this will append the text then get the scrollableHeight and then will scroll to it.

here is working playground demo:https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Rs0xnP&v=16

Comment: Tried your method, still doesn't work. I may have found the reason why - I logged the values of scrollView and it's scrollableHeight and while scrollView is good, scrollableHeight is set to 0 at all times, even when I can manually scroll down the page. Any comment on this? I tried embedding the `TextView` in a `StackLayout`, but no luck there either.

Comment: can you create the playground demo. then i can have a look.

Comment: Playground Link: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Rs0xnP

Comment: In case anyone get still 0 as scrollableHeight. I am not sure why, but without setTimeout it is not working. Handling the scrollable things in a setTimeout cb function solves the issue.

Comment: you can also try running this in NgZone.

Comment: in nativescript vue even settimeout doesn't help and scrollableHeight is still zero for me.

Comment: I have the same problem the difference is, that I am using a ListView as a child of the ScrollView, when I try to calculate the scrollableHeight always is 0.

Answer (score -1):

The function below can only be used in the Angular ngDoCheck() or ngAfterContentChecked() lifecycle:

```js
// See https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks
function goDownScrollView(scrollView: object, animate: boolean = true): boolean {

    let neScrollView:     ScrollView = <ScrollView>getNativeElement(scrollView),
        scrollableHeight: number     = neScrollView.scrollableHeight;

    console.log("neScrollView:", neScrollView);
    console.log("neScrollView scrollableHeight:", scrollableHeight);

    if (scrollableHeight > 0) {

        neScrollView.scrollToVerticalOffset(scrollableHeight, animate);
        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }

}
```

An helper to always get the native element:

```js
function getNativeElement(object: object): object {

    return (object.hasOwnProperty("nativeElement")) ? object['nativeElement'] : object;

}
```

**The scrollable height may be zero at the first pass of the lifecycle** (for example, if you add elements to your ScrollView with an HTTP request). That's why you have to test the current content with new before scroll:

```js
// See https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild
@ViewChild("content") private _pageContent: ElementRef<ScrollView>;

public  currentContent:   object;
private _previousContent: object;

...

ngAfterContentChecked(): void {

    if (this.currentContent != this._previousContent) {

        let isScrollDown: boolean = goDownScrollView(this._pageContent);

        if (isScrollDown) {

            this._previousContent = this.currentContent;

        }

    }

}
```